# How we can determine Bipartiteness in apache age graph?

Tags: postgresql, graph-theory, bipartite, apache-age

A graph is bipartite if and only if it is 2-colorable. Again A graph is bipartite if and only if every edge belongs to an odd number of bonds, minimal subsets of edges whose removal increases the number of components of the graph.

I have tried it but not understand how to implement it?

Comment: Wikipedia has [some suggestions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph#Testing_bipartiteness), not sure how to implement them in PostgreSQL or Apache AGE, though.

Answer (score 0):

Apache AGE is a graph database that uses PostgreSQL as its backend. This means that any functionality that is not provided out-of-the-box by AGE can be implemented in PostgreSQL using custom functions. In the case of determining bipartiteness of a graph, a custom function can be written in PostgreSQL and then used within an AGE query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python driver for apache-age to load the graph and implement a function to check if it is bipartite or not.

Check out [this article](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/implementing-a-graph-bipartition-checker-in-python-364b619a3d29) for further help.

Answer (score 0):

The statement you proved is not right because bipartite graph are only covered with 2 different colour that are not adjacent to each other.for e.g there are two colours red and blue red edge is connected to blue only [image: bipartite graph example]

Answer (score 0):

Apache AGE leverages the PostgreSQL ecosystem and allows you to utilize custom functions to implement additional functionality. In the case of determining the bipartiteness of a graph, you can write a custom function in PostgreSQL and then incorporate it into your AGE queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following steps to determine the  bipartiteness in the graph:

- Traverse the nodes of the graph using **graph traversal**.
- Assign numbers to the nodes (0 and 1).
- Make sure that **adjacent nodes** should have different colors.
- But if a conflict comes and a node has a same color as its neighbor then it is a **bipartite graph**.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to create a **custom function** using PostgreSQL to find bipartite-ness in a graph.

I think, as of now AGE doesn't support this feature but, you can implement it using Postgres because the AGE backend is created using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Apache AGE does not provide built-in automatic graph partioning, but you can integrate PostgreSQL which will allows you to implement various bipartitioning strategies at the PostgreSQL level.

- You can use Python drivers for Apache-AGE to load the graph and implement a function to check if it is bipartite or not.